# Subscribe FB event

Tags: facebook-like

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script>
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=223245147771570";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);}
(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
function(response) {
    alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
});</script>   
  <h1>Lajknout stranku!</h1>
  <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/Testra22" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="10" data-show-faces="false" data-font="trebuchet ms"></div>
```

I use this code to create FB Like button and I would like to display alert when user click on it. But there is js error Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You start using Facebook JS SDK before it was loaded by browser.

Because you use asynchronous way to load the JS SDK you need to define `window.fbAsyncInit` (as described in [documentation for JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)) function and run code that depend on JS SDK from here...

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
    alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
  });
}
```